# How do you configure an SDL Tridion CME extension for a subset of views?

Tags: gui-extensions

I have created a new editor for SDL Tridion which adds some new functionality to the ribbon bar.  This is enabled by adding the following snippet to the editor.config

```
    <!-- ItemCommenting PowerTool -->
    <ext:extension assignid="ItemCommenting" name="Save and&lt;br/&gt;Comment" pageid="HomePage" groupid="ManageGroup" insertbefore="SaveCloseBtn">
      <ext:command>PT_ItemCommenting</ext:command>
      <ext:title>Save and Comment</ext:title>
      <ext:issmallbutton>false</ext:issmallbutton>
      <ext:dependencies>
        <cfg:dependency>PowerTools.Commands</cfg:dependency>
      </ext:dependencies>
      <ext:apply>
        <ext:view name="*" />
      </ext:apply>
    </ext:extension>
```

This is applied to all views by using a wildcard value in the  node. This has results in my new button being added to the ribbon of every  view, including the main dashboard. Is there a way to add this to all views except for the dashboard? Or do I have to create something like this?

```
    <ext:apply>
        <ext:view name="PageView" />
        <ext:view name="ComponentView" />
        <ext:view name="SchemaView" />
    </ext:apply>
```

If this is the only way to achieve the result I need, is there a list of all the view names somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to define exceptions, but you can use some of the general views that apply to multiple items.

In this case, I think you can use EditorView in combination with the MainToolbar control:

```xml
<ext:view name="EditorView">
  <ext:control id="MainToolbar"/>
</ext:view>
```